# How to create a QUIC connection on Android?

Tags: android, quic

I'm writing an Android app in Java. I want to connect to a server using the QUIC protocol. What options do I have? The only thing (almost) that shows up during my searches is [Cronet](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet/), which is a networking library based on the network engine of Chrome, but it doesn't seem to be intended for you to just create a QUIC connection/socket/stream and start doing "raw" networking, but rather wraps the whole HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 over QUIC stack. The android docs also don't mention anything besides doing HTTP with it. But maybe I'm just missing something?

[Kwik](https://github.com/ptrd/kwik) is a full-blown Java implementation of QUIC, but the authors seem a bit hesitant to call it production ready, and I'm a little bit worried about performance here. Also it's not published on maven central.

Any other options I've been missing? With Google being the strongest proponent of QUIC, I'm surprised this isn't just part of their SDK by now.